# Explicit template instantiation outside of main .cpp file

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using [template dependency injection](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) to test a class with a dependency on non-virtual methods in code that I cannot change. I would like to [maintain the class's declaration and definition separately](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-class-defn-from-decl) as they were before. Both possible template instantiations are known at compile-time, and this may lead to less bloat/compile times. As described in the link, this can be done by explicitly instantiating the known template variants at the end of the `.cpp` file:

```
// "Foo.cpp"
#include "Foo.h"
// definition of Foo<T>::f() etc.
template class Foo<Bar>;
template class Foo<MockBar>;
```

However, this introduces test references in production code. Furthermore, if I try to forward-declare `MockBar` I get "invalid use of incomplete type" errors. If I include `MockBar.h` from `Foo.cpp` then I need to ensure that my build process is also adjusted to include and link any relevant test code with `Foo` (e.g. gmock), which seems wrong. If I move the `template class Foo<MockBar>` instantiation into `Foo_test.cpp` then I get undefined reference link errors for methods on it (but no error for the intended instantiation). I think I'm missing something about the instantiation process.

How can I keep the separate header approach whilst also separating test and production code?

Comment: You can have a "private" Foo.inl that you can use in test.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I mean in Foo.cpp and in FooTest.cpp, you have `#include "foo.inl"` (definition are in foo.inl, Foo.h have only forward declaration as now (public interface)).

Comment: Maybe you could expand that into a full answer? I.e where is my understand of instantiation lacking? Why does my method still fail to link? Why would Foo_test.cpp not just include Foo.cpp by your method?

Comment: I don't want to include `cpp`, that why I introduce .inl.

Comment: Seems to work, but not clear to me why this is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You may split your files in a different way and give access to implementation to your tests, something like:

Foo.h

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
    // member declaration ... 
};
```

Foo.inl

```
#include "Foo.h"

template <typename T>
void Foo::bar() { /*...*/ }
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.inl"
#include "Bar.h"

// Instantiations
template class Foo<Bar>;
// ...
```

And in FooTest.cpp

```
#include "Foo.inl"
#include "MockBar.h"

template class Foo<MockBar>;

// Test Foo<MockBar> ...
```

So normal users only use Foo.h
users which require Foo definition (as unittest) includes Foo.inl
Foo.inl may be a private include (not provide in "package").